# When updating my Cordova/Phoengap database?

Tags: database, cordova, sql-update, web-sql

I'm developing a Cordova/Phonegap App which includes a database that is synchronized with an external server (internet), the database server will change frequently, what advise me to keep my application updated?

I thought of two things:

1. Make a file called version.txt and including the version number, so I only need to see the file on the server and if it contains a greater number then run the update internal database.
2. Make a table with a version number and do the same as in item 1.

What You advise me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this by creating an endpoint on my server that returns a JSON object containing the current version number.

When my app loads it makes a request to the end point and compares the JSON return to a localStorage variable in the device.

Then (like you suggested above) if the JSON return is greater than the localStorage variable, the database is updated and then the localStorage variable is updated to the value of the current JSON return.

Example:

```
function updateDatabase () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://your_web_site.tdl/databaseversion/',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result, status, xhr) {
            var currentVersion = result.version;
            if(!window.localStorage.getItem('localVersion') || window.localStorage.getItem('localVersion') < currentVersion) {
                //UPDATE DATABASE CODE HERE
                window.localStorage.setItem('localVersion',currentVersion);
            }
            else{
                //NO NEED TO UPDATE
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            //CANNOT GET CURRENT VERSION FROM SERVER
        }

    });
}
```

This assumes that your server will return the JSON:

```
{ version: 'X' }
```

Comment: Thanks, but What does it mean: `localStorage variable in the device`?

Comment: localStorage is a key/value(string only) store available in Cordova (and in the html5 spec). You use `window.localStorage.setItem('key','value')` and `window.localStorage.getItem('key')`. This allows you to store variables in your application that are persistent and only go away if you clear your app cache or uninstall the app.

Comment: I'll consider your advice, +1 but is not the answer, because `and only go away if you clear your app cache ...` Users can use master cleaner or something else...

Comment: Well, in the case of the user clearing cache (by any means) the database would be cleared as well. So when your check ran, it would just update to the latest version any way.

Comment: And what will happen to the local variable in that case?

Comment: The very first time a user runs the app the variable is null, so the update runs and the variable gets set. So if the use were to clear app data, the app runs as if it were the first time and retrieve the latest data and set the variable again. This would be the case even with a native application.

Comment: Sounds good, Please, might you expand your answer for how to declare local variable, and how to send it JSON?

Comment: Excellent explanation, but, one last question, where would I declare "by first time" my local variable? Here?: `function onDeviceReady() {
        window.localStorage.setItem("localVersion", "1");}` Where do I put it so it does not rewrite and hold its value?

Comment: The example I provided will work as expected. localStorage is not scoped and is global accessible/writeable. For the first time load to work you will not want to define it anywhere else other than where it is in the example. The statement `if(!window.localStorage.getItem('localVersion') || window.localStorage.getItem('localVersion') < currentVersion)` is checking for if the variable does not exist yet or if it does exist check for a mis-match of value. In either case the variable will be set (either for the first time or updated) to the latest version number.